# Can't get Spring AOP to log/print in my application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-aop

Like the title says, here are my classes (this is just for testing if I can AOP to work):

ApplicationContextConfiguration.kt

```
package com.fdev.jobby

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class ApplicationContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun dataSource():DataSource{
        return DataSource()
    }
}
```

DataSource.kt

```
package com.fdev.jobby

open class DataSource {
    fun getDataFromDB(): String{
        // fetching Data
        return "data was loaded"
    }

    fun insertDataToDB(){
        // inserting Data
    }
}
```

LoggingDataSource.kt

```
package com.fdev.jobby

import mu.KotlinLogging
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Aspect
@Component
class LoggingDataSource {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.fdev.jobby.DataSource.*(..))")
    fun getAllMethods(){}

    @Before("getAllMethods()")
    fun startOfAccessToDB(){
        logger.error("Starting access to DB")
    }

    @AfterReturning("getAllMethods()")
    fun endOfAccessToDBSuccess(){
        println("Successful access to DB..")
    }

    @AfterThrowing("getAllMethods()")
    fun endOfAccessToDBFailure(){
        println("Failed access to DB..")
    }
}
```

AOPController.kt

```
package com.fdev.jobby

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("aop")
class AOPController(@Autowired val dataSource: DataSource) {

    @GetMapping("testing")
    fun aopTesting(): String{
        val data = dataSource.getDataFromDB()
        return data
    }
}
```

So when I call localhost:8080/aop/testing it shows the string "data was loaded" but it wont log or print my advices. What am I doing wrong? I have been reading [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop) but the docs seem very unintuitive and not helpful at all. Please help :(

Edit: my gradle dependencies look like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.1.20")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Comment: I can take a look if you publish a reproducer project on GitHub. I normally use Java or Groovy rather than Kotlin and Maven rather than Gradle, so if you help me to save a little bit of time, setting zup everything from scratch, I can look into it. By just reading the code, nothing immediately struck me as wrong, so I need to see for myself.

Comment: I found the solution, I had to put @Component in my data class so it scans properly and remove the bean from ApplicationContextConfiguration class

Comment: That alone should not be the root cause of the problem. Spring AOP should recognise `@Bean` declarations, too. Something else must be wrong with your configuration, but I have no way of finding out without the MCVE. So IMO, this problem is still unsolvd, even though your workaround works. Of course, the `@Component` annotation is what I would use by default, because it is easier than declaring a bean factory method. But the latter should work, too.